# Switch Case Producing Wrong Ouput

Tags: c, switch-statement, output

The output is supposed to be `5 10 14 18`. But even tough default case is executed it outputs `5 10 15 20`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
   int i=0;
   for(i=0;i<20;i++){
   switch(i){
       case 0: i+=5;  break;
       case 1: i+=2;  break;
       case 5: i+=5;  break;
       default: i+=4;   
   }
   printf("%d \n",i);
   }
}

Output - 
5 
10 
15 
20
```

Shouldnt the output be `5 10 14 18` ?

Comment: You can easily see such things in a debugger. For such a loop, it may also help to use paper and pencil and step through each iteration manually.

Comment: It is also rather meaningless to ponder about what nonsense code like this does. In a real program, you shouldn't increment the loop iterator variable anywhere but in the 3rd place of the for statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget `i` increments `1` in every `for` loop. Add another debugging print before `switch`, you can see it:

```
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
   printf("before %d \n",i);
   switch (i){
       case 0: i+=5;  break;
       case 1: i+=2;  break;
       case 5: i+=5;  break;
       default: i+=4;   
   }
   printf("after %d \n",i);
}
```

Output:

```
before 0 
after 5 
before 6 
after 10 
before 11 
after 15 
before 16 
after 20
```

Comment: Note that this behaviour is easily removed by doing `for(i=0; i<20;)` if that is what OP desires. Really, `i=0; while(i<20)` is then more suitable.

Answer (score 3):

Lets see:

```
i =  0, case + 5 = i=5
i =  6, case + 4 = i=10
i = 11, case + 4 = i=15
i = 16, case + 4 = i=20
```

The CPU is right

Answer (score 1):

You should get the output you expect if you remove the `i++` from the `for` loop :

```
for(i=0;i<20;){
```

For every iteration, you're both incrementing `i` in the `switch` statement, as well as the increment part of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

after 5 in printed, i becomes 6 , and then it goes to default where i becomes 10 and 10 is preinted. After this the for loop increases it by 1 and i becomes 11. Again goes to default which makes i =15 and hence 15 is printed. Again it increases by 1 , by for, and becomes 19 and goes to default again and i becomes 20. Please put a line, before the switch starts

```
     printf("value of i before switch:%d\n",i);
```

This will make u clear.
Plz keep in mind that for loop is also increamenting the value of i.
Dont increament the value of i in for loop to get the desired result.

Comment: Indent variables(i),for,numbers etc when posting an answer

Answer (score -1):

it's correct ... as u see u are incrementing "i" by (5) if the case is (0) so
{i --> 5}  then after the "i++" in the loop it becames (6).
so, then the switch case will switch to the default on the other cases of "i" because "i" became (6) then "i" will increment by (4) in the default case and by (1) in the loop (i++) ;

so the output is correct !!!!!!

Comment: Don't use brackets and inverted commas.Instead,use backticks and avoid using shortforms like u